# Loop through multiple sheets, look for specific value, paste cell with matching value to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I have 5 sheets that represent a phase. Each sheet has a unique ID that carries throughout. I have a status column and a for loop that copies and pastes the row as the status moves to the next stage. I am looking to add in script that will search for the Unique ID in previous sheets and update the status column for that ID as it moves through each phase. I tried using if statements to allow this to happen, but they are not updating properly. Here is an example:

```
Private Sub Execute_Click()

a = Worksheets("Execute").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Execute").Cells(i, 8).Value = "Complete" Then
        Worksheets("Execute").Rows(i).Range("A1:H1").Copy
        Worksheets("Complete").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Complete").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Complete").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        Worksheets("Execute").Cells(i, 8).Value = "In Production"
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Execute").Activate
        
    End If
    
    If Worksheets("Inventory").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("Execute").Cells(i, 3) Then
    
    Worksheets("Inventory").Cells(i, 8).Value = Worksheets("Execute").Cells(i, 8)

    End If
    
    If Worksheets("Prioritize").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("Execute").Cells(i, 3) Then
    
    Worksheets("Prioritize").Cells(i, 8).Value = Worksheets("Execute").Cells(i, 8)

    End If
    
    If Worksheets("Score").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("Execute").Cells(i, 3) Then
    
    Worksheets("Score").Cells(i, 8).Value = Worksheets("Execute").Cells(i, 8)
    
    End If
    
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

**Additional Info:**

The workbook will follow this exact same process for each tab (status). A row Item is uniquely identified by the concatenate column C – every new item in the workbook will start in Inventory then Prioritize -> Score -> Execute -> Complete. I have a for-loop macro written for each status change (i.e. Inventory to Prioritize, Prioritize to Score, Score to Execute, Execute to Complete.

The for-loop is working properly. When the status changes from one phase to the next the entire row from A:H will copy and paste into the next available row in the follow tab.
In addition to this happening, I also need column H (Status) to update for each unique ID on the previous tabs as it moves through the phases.

Here is an example of the workflow:

- **Step one:** Item in Inventory is sent to Prioritize
- **Step two:** A4:H4 is copied from Inventory and pasted into Prioritize - Inventory status updates to Prioritizing
- **Step three:** A4:H4 is pasted into Prioritize with the Prioritizing status
- **Step four:** Item in Prioritize is sent to Score
- **Step five:** A4:H4 is copied from Prioritize and pasted into Score - Prioritize status updates to Scoring
- **Step six:** The row that was updated to Scoring in the Prioritize tab needs to also update to Scoring in the Inventory tab

Step six is were I am running into trouble. This is where I wrote the If Statements – I am trying to use the If Statements to match on column C (Concatenate). For example: if column C in sheet “Execute” matches column C in sheet “Inventory” then Column H in sheet “Execute” = column H is sheet “Inventory”.  I am not getting any type error with the code, but when the macro is run sometimes the status will update properly on previous tabs and sometimes it will not. I am wondering if there is a better way to get these status to update?

Comment: I think a little sample data and desired output would aid comprehension.

Comment: It would also help to elaborate on "not updating properly".  Are you getting an error, the wrong data, no data, etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for the follow up questions. I added some additional information into my original post.. I hope this helps clarify a bit more. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the sheets in reverse order and use a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object) to hold the last status for each unique ID. Update later  sheets (earlier steps) with that status. This single script will move items through all phases.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateAll()

    Const COL_ID = 3 ' C
    Const COL_PHASE = 8 ' H

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws(5) As Worksheet
    Dim iLast(5) As Long, n As Integer, r As Long
    Dim iMoves As Long, iUpdates As Long
    Dim id As String, status As String
    Dim phase, newstatus
    phase = Array("", "Inventory", "Prioritize", "Score", _
                      "Execute", "Complete")
    newstatus = Array("", "Prioritizing", "Scoring", "Executing", "In Production")

    Dim dict As Object, key
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' step through sheets in reverse order
    For n = 5 To 1 Step -1

        Set ws(n) = wb.Sheets(phase(n))
        iLast(n) = ws(n).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For r = 2 To iLast(n)

            id = Trim(ws(n).Cells(r, COL_ID))
            status = Trim(ws(n).Cells(r, COL_PHASE))

            If n = 5 Then
                 dict.Add id, status
            ElseIf dict.exists(id) Then
                ' seen on earlier sheet - update status
                If ws(n).Cells(r, COL_PHASE) <> dict(id) Then
                    ws(n).Cells(r, COL_PHASE) = dict(id)
                    iUpdates = iUpdates + 1
                End If
            ElseIf LCase(status) = LCase(phase(n + 1)) Then
                'copy to next phase
                iLast(n + 1) = iLast(n + 1) + 1
                ws(n).Cells(r, COL_PHASE) = newstatus(n)
                ws(n).Range("A1:H1").Offset(r - 1).Copy _
                ws(n + 1).Range("A" & iLast(n + 1))
                dict.Add id, newstatus(n)
                iMoves = iMoves + 1
            Else
                ' new - update all previous sheets with this status
                dict.Add id, status
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox iMoves & " unique ID's moved on" & vbCr & _
           iUpdates & " updated", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much - this works perfectly! I really appreciate the help!